# Merge PST files

Tags: exchange, outlook

Is there a free tool that is good at merging pst files?  It seems outlook can do this, by using the import option, but when I tried it, it took over 4 hours for a 2GB pst file.  Anyone know of something better?

Comment: Although Outlook 2003 got rid of the 2GB limit on PSTs, merging files to make one bigger than 2GB seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Ward:  Most of it will be duplicates .... So I should have specified that I want it to be able to recognize duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Exchange the [exmerge](http://www.dtidata.com/resourcecenter/2007/05/11/exchange-server-tools-use-exmerge-import-pst-files/) tool can do it.  Not sure if it is any faster than Outlook, but it can deal with duplicates and will deal with multiple PSTs at a time.  Exmerge is provided with Exchange 2003, but it apparently [works with Exchange 2007](http://www.exchangeinbox.com/article.aspx?i=88).

If you have a bunch of mailboxes to do and aren't using Exchange, it might be worth setting up Exchange on some spare hardware to do this.  You can merge the PSTs into mailboxes, then export the mailboxes to new PSTs, and do it in batch.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do this?

Outlook is perfectly happy having the primary mailbox/OST/PST open and having additional PST files open at the same time.  Use the File/Open/Outlook Data File; and the second PST will show up as another branch in the Navigation pane.

A better alternative might be to have each user open the old/secondary PST files in Outlook and manually merge at their convenience.  If you want, give them a timeframe (say 90 days) before the PST files are removed and archived.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  People have ended up with two archive folders, and most of it is the same content...I'd rather not talk about it ...:-/

Comment: +1 for telling people to do it themselves, although I know how well that goes over for some people...

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but there is a tool called [PST Merge](http://www.pstmerge.com/) that claims to do just that.

Comment: Whereas I open both at the same time and drag the folders over (or run the Import / Export wizard and do the same but automatically.)

Comment: Ya, but not free :-(

Comment: I like the banner ad for PST Split: "Need your Outlook to run more faster?"